# Not able to send E-mail through IIS server (Working in local )

Tags: c#, .net, vba, smtp

I've been working on this from months, please someone help me solve this. Thanks

```
 try
        {
            SmtpClient smtpServer = new SmtpClient();
            MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
            smtpServer.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("iejabdb@otlook.com", "throughput");
            smtpServer.Port = 25;
            smtpServer.Host = "*****";
            smtpServer.EnableSsl = true;
            smtpServer.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
            mail.From = new MailAddress("*****@outlook.com", "Work Order System");
            mail.To.Add("*******@outlook.com");
            // mail.To.Add(receiptsArray.ToString());
            mail.Subject = "Test";
            mail.Body = "Hello";
            smtpServer.Send(mail);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Test this Code:

```
        MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
        SmtpClient SmtpServer = new SmtpClient("smtp.live.com");

        mail.From = new MailAddress("mawlud.f.m@hotmail.com");
        mail.To.Add("mawlud.f.m@gmail.com");

        mail.Subject = "Mail Subject";
        mail.Body = "Mail Body";

        SmtpServer.Port = 587;
        SmtpServer.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("mawlud.f.m@hotmail.com", "Write Your Password");

        SmtpServer.EnableSsl = true;
        SmtpServer.Send(mail);
```

Comment: Thank you, I tried it and it is not even working in local host. only    Outlook.MailItem oMsg = (Outlook.MailItem)oApp.CreateItem(Outlook.OlItemType.olMailItem);